# constexpr and deprecated conversion warning

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11

I'm writing a function as part of an experiment with Boost.Interprocess. In the function I assign a string literal to a variable declared `constexpr char*`. When I do this, I get:

`warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to char* [-Wwrite-strings]`.

My understanding of `constexpr` is that in a variable declaration it behaves as if the variable was declared `const`, but with the added stipulation that the variable must be initialized, and that initialization must be with a constant expression.

With this understanding I would expect `constexpr char*` to behave as `const char*`, and therefore not issue the warning. Am I missing something about how `constexpr` works?

I'm compiling with GCC 4.6.0 20110306 using -std=c++0x.

Any reasoning for the warning being issued would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `const` from `constexpr` would make your variable `char* const`.

You still have the problem that the string literal is `const char` and that converting its address to `char*` is allowed, but deprecated.

Comment: Thanks. I overlooked the other `const` of pointers. I changed the declaration to `constexpr const char*` and the warning disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

For another solution to this:

Instead of-

```
constexpr char* foo = "bar";
```

You can do-

```
constexpr char foo[] = "bar";
```

This will also get rid of the warning.